# How to activate "treat warning as error" for specific build definitions?

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

I would like to make my main branch TFS build definitions to treat warnings as errors so that the build fails when the projects are not error free. Since I do not want to activate "treat error as warning" in all project as a default, my first idea was to add a powershell script to my main build definition that substitues false with true in the line `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>...</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` in all csproj files it finds (something along the line of [this](https://gist.github.com/pietergheysens/14d7d98547fe35470d0e)). Is there any better/straighter way via some option as part of the build definition settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the build definition specify /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=True in the MSBuild argument field.

This will override any setting from the csproj files.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no this kind of settings  as part of the build definition.

However, you could be able to return warnings and errors from your powershell script using [**logging commands**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573).  With using `task.logissue type=error` you could fail the build task and then fail the build.

More details you could take a look at this similar question: [Is it possible to raise and display build warnings from build steps using TFS 2015](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573)